# Pulling variables from a .csv to build a JSON output

Tags: json, csv, jq

I have a .csv file with a short list of variables that I need to create a .json file out of. Everything is working perfectly to a point but one of the variables ($input[5]/"programNumber") needs to be imported as an integer and the script I am using is pulling everything with a set of quotes which works fine for the first 4 variables. I'm just not familiar enough with the importing syntax to figure it out. Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is the script:

```
jq -Rsn '
   {"services":
      [inputs
         | . / "\n"
         | (.[] | select(length > 0) | . / ",") as $input
         |   {
               "type": "mpeg2tsUdp",
               "sources":
               [
                  {
                    "address": $input[1],
                    "port": 2000,
                    "sourceAddresses":
                    [
                        $input[3]
                    ],
                    "programSelection":
                    {
                        "type": "PmtProgramNumber",
                        "programNumber": $input[5]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "address": $input[2],
                    "port": 2000,
                    "sourceAddresses":
                    [
                        $input[4]
                    ],
                    "programSelection":
                    {
                        "type": "PmtProgramNumber",
                        "programNumber": $input[5]
                    }
                  }
               ],
               "streams": [],
               "id": $input[0]
            }
         ],
         "id": "Inputs",
         "name": "Inputs"
      }
' <SourceList.csv
```

and here is the .csv contents:

```
FNCHD,239.194.208.9,239.194.216.9,10.110.208.9,10.110.216.9,23
MTV,239.194.208.216,239.194.216.216,10.110.208.216,10.110.216.216,702
AEHD,239.194.208.6,239.194.216.6,10.110.208.6,10.110.216.6,1
SLATE,239.1.1.1,239.1.2.1,10.100.1.1,10.100.2.1,3
```

and here is the output:

````
{
  "services": [
    {
      "type": "mpeg2tsUdp",
      "sources": [
        {
          "address": "239.194.208.9",
          "port": 2000,
          "sourceAddresses": [
            "10.110.208.9"
          ],
          "programSelection": {
            "type": "PmtProgramNumber",
            "programNumber": "23"
          }
        },
        {
          "address": "239.194.216.9",
          "port": 2000,
          "sourceAddresses": [
            "10.110.216.9"
          ],
          "programSelection": {
            "type": "PmtProgramNumber",
            "programNumber": "23"
          }
        }
      ],
      "streams": [],
      "id": "FNCHD"
    },
    {
      "type": "mpeg2tsUdp",
      "sources": [
        {
          "address": "239.194.208.216",
          "port": 2000,
          "sourceAddresses": [
            "10.110.208.216"
          ],
          "programSelection": {
            "type": "PmtProgramNumber",
            "programNumber": "702"
          }
        },
        {
          "address": "239.194.216.216",
          "port": 2000,
          "sourceAddresses": [
            "10.110.216.216"
          ],
          "programSelection": {
            "type": "PmtProgramNumber",
            "programNumber": "702"
          }
        }
      ],
      "streams": [],
      "id": "MTV"
    },
    {
      "type": "mpeg2tsUdp",
      "sources": [
        {
          "address": "239.194.208.6",
          "port": 2000,
          "sourceAddresses": [
            "10.110.208.6"
          ],
          "programSelection": {
            "type": "PmtProgramNumber",
            "programNumber": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "address": "239.194.216.6",
          "port": 2000,
          "sourceAddresses": [
            "10.110.216.6"
          ],
          "programSelection": {
            "type": "PmtProgramNumber",
            "programNumber": "1"
          }
        }
      ],
      "streams": [],
      "id": "AEHD"
    },
    {
      "type": "mpeg2tsUdp",
      "sources": [
        {
          "address": "239.1.1.1",
          "port": 2000,
          "sourceAddresses": [
            "10.100.1.1"
          ],
          "programSelection": {
            "type": "PmtProgramNumber",
            "programNumber": "3"
          }
        },
        {
          "address": "239.1.2.1",
          "port": 2000,
          "sourceAddresses": [
            "10.100.2.1"
          ],
          "programSelection": {
            "type": "PmtProgramNumber",
            "programNumber": "3"
          }
        }
      ],
      "streams": [],
      "id": "SLATE"
    }
  ],
  "id": "Inputs",
  "name": "Inputs"
}```




Anything I tried; including removing the quotes around \n and ",", either failed the script completely or changed nothing.
````

Comment: Why don't you just convert it using `tonumber`? (e.g. `"programNumber": ($input[5] | tonumber)`)

Comment: I cannot believe it was that simple ... Brillirant. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a condensed version using `tonumber` just once:

```bash
jq -Rn '{
  services: [
    inputs | select(length > 0) / "," | {
      type: "mpeg2tsUdp",
      sources: [range(2) as $i | {
        address: .[1+$i],
        port: 2000,
        sourceAddresses: [.[3+$i]],
        programSelection: {
          type: "PmtProgramNumber",
          programNumber: .[5] | tonumber
        }
      }],
      streams: [],
      id: .[0]
    }
  ],
  id: "Inputs",
  name: "Inputs"
}' < SourceList.csv
```